# How can I install ubuntu on a server that has openfiler already?

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on this server Dell 1750, but it has openfiler. I reboot the server with the CD already in, but it won't read it or do anything. Are there any specific command on openfiler that I need to use in order for me to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is openfiler? Probably you need to get into BIOS and change the boot sequence so that CD is before HDD. Other way is to keep pressing the proper key that has description at pre-boot screen: boot menu.

Comment: Openfiler is an Open Source Network Attached Storage and Storage Area Network Solution, so basically your running your Computer in Linux, and you don't have windows xp, vista, server etc anymore. Let me try to get into bios and do what you told me, hopefully will work. Thanks!!!!